# Could some one Interpret this for me please? TY

Tags: translation

Could some one interpret this for me? Please and thank you!

[image]

Comment: I might be mistaken, but is that not Korean?

Comment: I am not sure ...Not fluent in either but That is a start for me thank you...how by chance could you tell that?

Comment: Based on the structure of the symbols and their components. While different Chinese scripts can look rather different (especially seal script), these don't really look like Chinese characters in a script I don't recognize. Plus, their overall structure reminds me strongly of Hangul (I don't really know Hangul, just its overall look): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul

You may even be able to use the Wikipedia page to figure out the symbols yourself. Hangul is a relatively simple and straightforward system (rather alphabet-like).

Answer (score 5):

As was mentioned, the top three characters 크리스 is the Korean spelling of "Chris".  The bottom three 랜달인 is either the name Randalin (or something similar), or Randall with the extra 인 to mean "stamp".

Until recently, Korea and Japan traditionally had this system of using carved wood personal stamps for identification purposes (they have largely been replaced by signature identification in Korea).  The carved image is usually of the name of the person in an enclosing circle just like in your picture, and some of them have an extra "인" as the last character which just states that it is a stamp.

So my guess is it is the image of personal stamp of someone named 크리스 랜달 (Chris Randall).

Comment: Yes, this looks like an Anglican name written in hangeul. These 도장 (seal stamps) are very common souvenirs for Westerners to purchase. I own several myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
kŭ   ri  sŭ
raen dal in
```

no idea what it means but if the top line is read left to right maybe 'Chris' the English given name?